# Angular 2/Firebase - with ngFor, prevent new data from loading automatically until user refresh

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Angular 2 and firebase. Currently I have a list of items and when a user adds to that list using a textbox the item is automatically added to that list without refreshing, this is great, but not what I want.. I don't want the list to grow, but instead tell the user `x new items available. click to refresh`.. if that makes sense..

This is my `html`:

```
<div *ngFor="let post of postFeed.reverse()"></div>
```

This loads my data automatically.

and this is my `ts`:

```
this.subscription = this.database.database.ref('/posts/'+this.userData.uid)
      .orderByChild('created')
      .startAt(new Date().getTime() - (24 * 3600 * 1000)) //last 24 hrs
      .limitToLast(10);
      this.subscription.on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
            this.postFeed.push(snapshot.val())
      });
```

I want to keep it as `.on` as the `post` has other variables to it like upvoting/downvoting and if I remove the `on` they won't load automatically..

How could I do it that instead of loading the newest `postFeed` when it gets added, instead tell the user that there has been a new post and if they would like to load it...

Thank you! I hope my question was clear.

Comment: You should just write your own helper methods to say if user clicked refresh run this, otherwise just run a diff. Without more details we can't really do much and it seems like you haven't really attempted anything. [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MikeTung I'm not really sure where to start to be honest

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you need, but why don't you put a boolean variable to check if there is a new data and use this boolean to ask users if they want to load it. If they do, just do the query ?

Comment: Ideas: store a count of records and listen for increases, listen on next 10  records in background but don't show them, query for more records on some interval (e.g. every 20 seconds), use a separate array for displayed list and synced list and copy synced into displayed when prompted.